# Approximating binomial probability distruibution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am studying Statistical Methods in my PG course. I came across Binomial distribution and here a question is given somewhat like this:

> According to BSNL, 71% of internet users connect their computers to
>   the internet by normal telephone lines. Assume a population proportion
>   p = 0.71.
>
> A. What is the probability that a sample proportion from a simple of
>   the random sample of 350 internet users will within +/-0.5 of the population
>   proportion?

I worked out and know that I have to assume population proportion to be 0.71. My question is how to check population proportion within a specified range like the case in the question, i.e., +/-0.5.

Comment: You are probably expected to use the normal approximation. If $\bar{X}$ is the sample proportion, then $\bar{X}$ has approximately normal distribution, mean $0.71$, variance $\frac{(0.71)(0.29)}{350}$, so standard deviation the square root of that. It is not clear what you mean by $0.5$. Is it $1/2$ of $1$ percent? Or is it plain $0.5$?

Comment: Ok that means I was on a wrong track. Thanks.